# How do I echo based on user level? (Other posts haven't helped much)

Tags: php, html

I'm having trouble with a user level system, I want to make different things appear based on if you are logged in or not and nothing I try has worked. I can echo a normal string just fine, but it I use an if statement to check user level I get nothing. I have a database with a sample user, and his user_level field is set to 1. The log in process is successful, here is what I have:

By the way, session_start(); is in the included base.php.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php
include "base.php";
?>
<head>
<title> Scenery Sample Site | Home</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster'
rel='stylesheet'          type='text/css'>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<div class="nav">
<div class="container">
    <ul class="pull-left">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Feedback</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="pull-right">
    <?php 

    if($_SESSION['user_level'] = 1) {
        echo $username;
    }
    ?>

    </ul>
</div>
</div>

<div class="jumbotron">
<div class="container">
<h1>Scenery for your favourite<br> destinations!</h1>
<p>Learn more about our products by clicking the link below.</p>
<p><a href="products.html">Visit our product page.</a></p>
</div>
</div>


<div class="we-offer">
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <h3>Custom Building Models!</h3>
    <p>All of our scenery models are custom made by our developers.</p>
    <p><a>More Details Here!</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class= "col-md-4">
    <h3>State of The Art Texturing!</h3>
    <p>All of our scenery textures are custom, and of the highest quality.    You will have to make sure you're not watching real life.</p>
    <p><a>More Details Here!</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <h3>Moving Jet-ways!</h3>
    <p>A lot of competitors remove the functionality of moving jetways that fsx comes with. Well guess what, we don't!</p>
    <p><a>More Details Here!</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class= "thumbnail">
            <img src="http://goo.gl/ZRT5E6">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class= "col-md-4">
        <div class= "thumbnail">
            <img src="http://goo.gl/KsocGR">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class= "thumbnail">
            <img src="http://goo.gl/3UfG97">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: Where does `$username` come from ? try to `echo "foobar"`; just to see if you get inside your `if` statement. Also, move your include "base.php" at the top of your file, `session_start` should be called before starting to output content.

Comment: The if statement works, all of the stuff like username and LoggedIn == 1 is in my base.php. I got foobar to display, but was unable to get username to display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't **check** the string, you try to assign it.

Remember: With a single = you assign to a variable, you don't check it.

Your have to do it like this:

```
if($_SESSION["user_level"] == 1) {
    echo "fancy fancy";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume the rest of this, including setting that session value is correct, and say: 
You're not using the correct operator.  use a double "=".

```
if($_SESSION['user_level'] == 1) {
            echo $username;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning instead of checking, this should help:

```
<?php 

    if($_SESSION['user_level'] == 1) {
        echo $username;
    }
?>
```